# How to add a arrow beside a vertical nav menue with bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

i have the following standard vertical nav menue

```
 <div id="menue" style="float:left;">
 <ul class="nav flex-column">
      <li class="nav-item navtab1">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item navtab2">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item navtab3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content" style="float:left;">
<div id="tab_1">my content for nav 1</div>
<div id="tab_2">my content for nav 2</div>
<div id="tab_3">my content for nav 3</div>

</div>
```

Now i want to add a arrow right beside of the active navigation part.

For example something like this
[image]

How i can do this with css?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of arrow? Give us the `CSS`?

Comment: @berkobienb sure - I've add a picture to make it more clear what i mean

Comment: where is CSS???

Comment: I've no css thats my question, i dont know how this can realize with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find a way to come near to this what i'm looking for.

I oversize the active tab, so it is larger as the other ones and goes a little bit into the div besides of themself.

```
width: calc(100% + 1rem) !important;
```

it's ok for me, for the moment...